# Sharing Docker daemon between WSL instances

Tags: docker, sharing, wsl-2

Regarding *running Docker from within WSL without Docker Desktop*, there is a comprehensive article [here](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9). However,

When it comes to *sharing the Docker daemon between WSL instances*, the article only touches the starting bits. This is to ask for the *whole* process.

First of all, why configuring it to use a socket stored in the shared /mnt/wsl directory, instead of commonly suggested exposing the 2375 port from docker? The reason I'm asking is that I found it challenging to find something to be used as the shared /mnt/wsl directory between different WSL instances, as trying to make use of exiting Windows drive (ntfs share mount) will be peoples' first instinct, however, it won't work. I tried that, trying to [call `mknod` to create a device file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241200/374303) in ntfs shared folder, and got:

`mknod: /mnt/d/foobar: Operation not supported`

Is it [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71245829/2125837),

> The issue is that Docker runs in 2375 but its bound just for localhost in some setups (WSL2 backend / Linux container)

Is it still true? But even that, it's fine with my above case as I'm only sharing the Docker daemon between WSL instances on the same localhost.

So, this is to ask for a total solution for sharing the Docker daemon between WSL instances, that is practical and anyone can follow. thx!

Comment: KW: how to configure the docker server under Linux/WSL2 to expose TCP port 2375.

Comment: I would highly recommend podman. podman is a daemonless container engine, so you don't need multiple WSL instances for daemon/clients, and it's near 100% Docker compatible. Some say it's "Docker made right". Highly recommended. You can grab the latest binaries here: https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.1.0

Comment: That's a good advice @valiano, but I need to share my Docker daemon to ***WSL1*** instances.